# How to Populate Lookup name Instead of Lookup Ids

Tags: trigger

I have 3 objects. "***document***" and "***product***" and **Junction platform** is child object for both "document"and "product".

In "document" object contains **productPartRevisionSOSL**  field there I need to populate ***product name***  values separted by comma.

I would like to populate product name instead of lookup ids in document Level

```
 public class s360_JunctionRevisionDetails {
public static void JunctionInsert(List < Junction_Revision__c > revisionList) {
    set < id > productids = new set < id > ();
    set < id > documentid = new set < id > ();
    map < Id, string > acmap = new map < Id, string > ();

    for (Junction_Revision__c jun: revisionList) {

            productids.add(jun.Product__c);
            documentid.add(jun.Document__c);


    }
    map < id, product2 > prodmap = new map < id, product2 > ([select id, name from product2 where id in: productids]);

    //iam getting nullmpointer exception in the below code

    for (Junction_Revision__c junc:revisionList ) {

        if (acmap.containskey(junc.Document__c)) {

            acmap.put(junc.Document__c, acmap.get(junc.Document__c) + ',' + prodmap.get(junc.Product__c).name);
        } else {
            acmap.put(junc.Document__c, prodmap.get(junc.Product__c).name);   //this line causes issue
        }
    }

    List < Document__c > doclist1 = new list < Document__c > ();

    List < Document__c > docList = [select id, PartRevisionSOSL__c from Document__c where id in: acmap.keyset()];
    for (Document__c doc: docList) {

            if (String.isBlank(doc.PartRevisionSOSL__c) == null) {
                doc.PartRevisionSOSL__c = acmap.get(doc.id);

            } else{
                doc.PartRevisionSOSL__c = doc.PartRevisionSOSL__c + ',' + acmap.get(doc.id);
            }


        doclist1.add(doc);
    }

    update doclist1;

}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Stacktrace would help

Comment: Update your question with the  stack trace

Comment: At what line is that happening?

Comment: May be because of the way you've structured your question, causing you to get the down votes. It's not very clear to understand.

Comment: okay.I have updated the question with image.Please check it once

Comment: How does this image relate to the rest of your question? Your title suggests you are receiving an exception, but the image you posted suggests the trigger works but doesn't do what you want. Would you please add a detailed description to your question of what the problem is, and if it is an exception, include the entire stack trace?

Comment: @david reeed I have modified the code now.so it works,instead of id I would like to populate product name.

Comment: While I did not downvote your question, I suspect you're accumulating downvotes because you have us playing guessing games. The body of this post does not contain a question. Please put this information *there* with a specific request for what aid you need to achieve that goal.

Comment: Please check it now.I just updated question as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have formatted your trigger code and inserted annotations and comments inline below.

Your logic is very messy, and you have two specific issues that lead to this exception.

1. You are querying the wrong set of `Junction_Revision__c` objects within the trigger handler, which as far as I can tell you do not need to do.
2. You are indexing directly into a field of an object returned from `Map.get()` in a situation where the object is actually `null`. It is `null` due to error (1).

Please see the comments below for more explication.

```
public class s360_JunctionRevisionDetails {
    public static void JunctionInsert(List < Junction_Revision__c > revisionList) {
        set < id > productids = new set < id > ();
        set < id > documentid = new set < id > ();
        map < Id, string > acmap = new map < Id, string > ();

        for (Junction_Revision__c jun: revisionList) {
            // There is no need for this `if` condition, as the parents of a junction object will never be `null`.
            if (jun.Product__c != null && jun.Document__c != null) {
                productids.add(jun.Product__c);
                documentid.add(jun.Document__c);

            }
        }
        map < id, product2 > prodmap = new map < id, product2 > ([select id, name from product2 where id in: productids]);

        // Why are you re-querying `Junction_Revision__c` objects that are already part of your trigger set?
        // This pulls in any `Junction_Revision__c` with the same `Document__c` as one of the records affected in the trigger.
        // This is one of the sources that contributes to your issues (see below for more).
        for (Junction_Revision__c junc: [select id, Document__c, Product__c from Junction_Revision__c where Document__c in: documentid]) {
            // This logic is backwards. You're essentially prepending `null` to the result here, and then overwriting with each result past the first.
            if (!acmap.containskey(junc.Document__c)) {
                // This is almost certainly the source of your NullPointerException. Because you are pulling in all `Junction_Revision__c` objects 
                // with the same `Document__c` as one of your trigger set objects, you will get back some  `Junction_Revision__c` records whose Products
                // are not part of the set of products you already queried based on the records in the trigger set.
                acmap.put(junc.Document__c, acmap.get(junc.Document__c) + ',' + prodmap.get(junc.Product__c).name);
            } else {
                acmap.put(junc.Document__c, prodmap.get(junc.Product__c).name);
            }
        }

        List < Document__c > doclist1 = new list < Document__c > ();
        // Why is the query below not written against `documentid`?
        List < Document__c > docList = [select id, PartRevisionSOSL__c from Document__c where id in: acmap.keyset()];
        for (Document__c doc: docList) {
            // You don't need to check if `acmap` contains this key, because you just queried based on `acmap` containing this key.
            if (acmap.containskey(doc.Id)) {
                // `String.isBlank(doc.PartRevisionSOSL__c)` is usually preferable, because it checks for null, empty, or all-whitespace.
                if (doc.PartRevisionSOSL__c == null) {
                    doc.PartRevisionSOSL__c = acmap.get(doc.id);
                // This doesn't need to be an `else if`. It's just the opposite of your `if` branch.
                } else if (doc.PartRevisionSOSL__c != null)
                    doc.PartRevisionSOSL__c = doc.PartRevisionSOSL__c + ',' + acmap.get(doc.id);
            }
            doclist1.add(doc);
        }

        update doclist1;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks..Iam requerying junction revison object in case if document already contains some junction revision records for updating those records product name in document level

Comment: Well, I don't understand that logic myself, but the combination of (1) and (2) is causing your NullPointerException.

Comment: yes.I just updated the question please check it. please check my comment line

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for, Annappa. Respectfully, I've already provided what I think is the answer, and I've spent quite a bit of time on this question. I would suggest you work to finish debugging this code and, if you need to, post a new, clear question about one specific issue.

Comment: Okay sure.Thanks David Reed.You are comments are really helpfull,I will debug it..,Thanks

Comment: I have tried this logic: .Iam requerying junction revison object in case if document already contains some junction revision records for updating those records product name in document level ...that causes the issue..Thank you so much @David Reed

Answer (score 0):

You can't give `map<id,id> productrevision=new map<id,id>();` a string of name at `productrevision.put(pc.id,pc.name);`. You need to change it to `map<id,String> productrevision=new map<id,String>();` if you want to do that

Update

```
map<id,id> productrevision=new map<id,id>();
for(product2 pc:productList){
        productrevision.put(pc.id,pc.name); //You can't do this.
    }
```

It needs to be

```
map<id,string> productrevision=new map<id,string>();
for(product2 pc:productList){
        productrevision.put(pc.id,pc.name); 
    }
```

Comment: I dont think that line issue in that code.I havent use that "productversion"map anywhere

Comment: @AnnappaPH Updated..  and you're right, you don't use `productversion` anywhere

Comment: I dont know why Iam getting down votes for this question.ya I got your point,,thats not a issue.. If i change that code according to your suggestion also it doesnt work for me

Comment: Update your question with the changes then with a stack trace